# TabItem id not showing up in TabLayout.Tab

Tags: android, android-tabs

I've defined my tabs in xml like this:

```
<TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TabItem
        android:id="@+id/firstTab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading1"/>
```

But when I query the currently selected tab id like this:

```
tabs.getTabAt(tabs.selectedTabPosition).id
```

I get -1. I was expecting to get the value of `firstTab`. When I however query for the text:

```
tabs.getTabAt(tabs.selectedTabPosition).text
```

it correctly returns the text from `heading1`.

I noticed that [TabItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabItem) does not define an id. Android Studio however does not complain  when I slip it an id.

Now I guess I could just fall back to doing a string comparison with the text, that is correctly transfered to `TabLayout.Tab`. Doesn't seem right to me though. Is there another way to identify the currently selected tab?

---

**EDIT:**

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
when (tabs.getTabAt(tabs.selectedTabPosition).id) {
    firstTab -> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

AndroidStudio does not complain because in the xml you have a `TabItem` which lets you set text, icon and custom layout ([docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabItem)). This is then converted into a `TabLayout.Tab` ([docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab)) which has an id.

You use a TabSelectionListener to store the current selected tab:

```
 addOnTabSelectedListener(
        object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
        }
    )
```

---

As you know the sequence of your tabs you could use a `when` statement with `selectedTabPosition` to handle your use case:

```
const val HEADLINE_POSITION = 0 // or just number in when statement

when(selectedTabPosition){
    HEADLINE_POSITION -> // do logic for first tab
    -1 -> // do logic if nothing is selected 
    else -> // default
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I think using the `selectedTabPosition` is the best way as you know the sequence of your tabs. Unfortunately the `id` from the xml is dropped when creating the `TabLayout.Tab`s. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hm.. I know the sequence of the tabs from the XML. However, if I were to change that order, I need to remember to also change some magic numbers in the `when` expression. Doesn't seem very clean to me. But if this really is my best bet, I think I'll go for it.